# How to add ordered list icon to rich text editor in html mode for sitecore 10

Tags: sitecore-client, richtext-editor

Using `Sitecore 10.0.1`
I want to add `ordered list icon` to Sitecore `rich text editor` when opening in HTML mode.
How do we achieve this?

Comment: Add some more details to your question. You want to achieve this in Content Editor or Experience Editor? And a screenshot showing where you want this button to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On you item template, you can provide the RTE source like this.

[image]

And when you open the Show Editor button in RTE, you will find the option to add the Ordered List like this.

[image]

Here are some more source options available as per your needs.

- /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Default
- /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full
- /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text IDE
- /sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Medium

Read more in details.

https://himynameistim.com/blog/optimize-the-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore

Comment: This solution worked

Comment: @coder Yes Under Sitecore.config set the value `<setting name="HtmlEditor.DefaultProfile" value="/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text IDE" />` it will apply for all.

Comment: @coder Please follow this article to create a patch. https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/use-a-patch-file-to-customize-the-sitecore-configuration.html

Comment: Now the unordered list icon shows in Rich text editor but in cms site, the bullet points is not coming though it is <list>. Any suggestions?

Comment: That may be some css issue, Can you please check?